# How to position 3 divs on the same line?

Tags: html, css, joomla

How to position 3 divs - 3 chunks of text link on the same line in left, center and right?

I need it to position under Joomla article 3 navigation links: PREV, INDEX, NEXT  - on the same line...PREV - on left, INDEX - center and NEXT-right;

I know I cannot use float, because there is no float center; if I am trying to use  divs - they are not on the same line again...

for example I was trying with

```
<div style="width:700px;">
<div style="width:50px; margin-left:20px;">Prev</div>

<div style="width:50px; margin-left:350px;">Index</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HAL6s/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="equal left">PREV</div>
    <div class="equal center">INDEX</div>
    <div class="equal right">NEXT</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.wrapper{width:100%; display:table;}
.equal{display:table-cell;}
.left{text-align:left;}
.center{text-align:center;}
.right{text-align:right;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put a div in the center of the page horizontally, you can use the css

> `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 <div class="main">
        <div class="div1">
         <div class="div2"></div>
         <div class=="div3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
       </div>
```

and in css

```
.div1 {
  float:left;
}
.div4 {
float:right;
}
.div2 {
float:left;
}
.div3 {
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it via a list like so:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>Prev</li>
    <li>Next</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.pagination {
    width: 700px;
}
ul.pagination li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:700px;">
<div style="width:50px; margin-left:20px;display: inline-block;">Prev</div>

<div style="width:50px; margin-left:350px;display: inline-block;">Index</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HAL6s/1/)**

```
.master{width:100%; text-align:center; }
.master div{display:inline}
.left{float:left}
.right{float:right}
```